# Inconsistent load order behavior for the resources loaded with <link rel="preload"> (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, http, cross-browser

I'm experimenting with dynamically adding `<link rel="preload">` tag for loading font files based on the user connection `navigator.connection.effectiveType`, e.g. if effective type is '4g' inject  `<link as="font" type="font/woff2" rel="preload" crossorigin="anonymous" href="inter-var.woff2">` in the `head` tag before any other resources, if connection is 'slow-2g' / '2g' / '3g' don't inject `link`.

I'm also loading other resources using `preload`, but they are not as critical as fonts thus they are injected after the font files.

```
<head>
  // some other code
  <script id="connection-type-checker">
    (() => {
      const inter = document.createElement('link')
      const interItalic = document.createElement('link')
      const firaCode = document.createElement('link')

      inter.as = 'font'
      inter.type = 'font/woff2'
      inter.rel = 'preload'
      inter.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
      inter.href = 'inter-var.woff2'

      interItalic.as = 'font'
      interItalic.type = 'font/woff2'
      interItalic.rel = 'preload'
      interItalic.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
      interItalic.href = 'inter-var-italic.woff2'

      firaCode.as = 'font'
      firaCode.type = 'font/woff2'
      firaCode.rel = 'preload'
      firaCode.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
      firaCode.href = 'fira-code.woff2'

      const insertAfter = (newNode, referenceNode) => referenceNode
        .parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling)

      const target = document.getElementById('connection-type-checker')

      insertAfter(inter, target)
      insertAfter(interItalic, target)
      insertAfter(firaCode, target)
    })()
  </script>

  // **This is where <link>s get injected**

  // some other code...

  <link as="script" rel="preload" href="script.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

The problem I'm facing is that Chrome doesn't keep the original order for resources loaded with link preload if the `link` element was created with JavaScript (if link elements are inlined as HTML in the `head` tag everything works as expected).

- [Example](https://github.com/iamskok/dynamic-link-preload-test)
- [Repo](https://github.com/iamskok/dynamic-link-preload-test)

Screenshot:

- Safari (respects the original order)
- Chrome (doesn't respect the original order)
- Firefox (doesn't support link preload)

[image: Safari, Chrome, Firefox]

I'm trying to understand why the original order is breaking in Chrome and if it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome engineer here. There are a few inconsistencies here, from what I can tell:

1. First, you can see Firefox is actually fetching the `image.jpeg` before the preloads as well, given your picture
2. Second, I can actually occasionally get Safari to produce an odd ordering too:

[image: Safari ordering]

What you're seeing here is Chrome's (and some other browsers') background HTML parser at work, which is just another lightweight parser that quickly rips through the page looking for resources to speculatively (early) fetch. From debugging Chrome a bit on the example page you've created, the order of events happening is roughly:

1. Speculative parser kicks off a request for `script.js`
2. Speculative parser kicks off a request for `image.jpeg`
3. Normal parser executes the document's pending parsing-blocking script
4. The three preloads are fetched, in the order they were added

So in this case you're seeing the speculative/background parser jump ahead a bit, and start fetching things before the main parser is able to via your `script` tag. Most browsers have this kind of parser [here's an article about it](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2013/big-bad-preloader/), and unfortunately it is not specified by any standard, since it is not supposed to have any observable (to application code) effects.

However, if you're seeing a performance problem due to this, your best bet is to file a Chromium bug on https://crbug.com and maybe let me know and I can get it in front of the right people.

P.S. I noticed you filed https://github.com/w3c/preload/issues/146, which I'll probably close in favor of you filing a Chrome bug if that's OK.

Comment: The bug was reported https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1074587 

Comment: Thanks, I've cc'd someone on the bug

Comment: Thank you so much!

Can you think of any way I can trick background HTML parser and load resources in the exact order?

Comment: Without radically changing the document's layout, I don't think there's much you can do honestly. There are some plans to make the Background HTML parser yield to the main thread in Chrome, but I'm not sure how much that intersects with this issue: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?oldui=1#!topic/loading-dev/rhHhUoZ4LD4